# AWS Step Function to Invoke Lambda - Fast Execution - No Error - Seemingly Not Invoking Logic

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am running into a situation that I haven't come across.  I am deploying my python lambda via a SAM app.  After deploying, I manually invoke the lambda in the console and it works exactly as designed.

A second test, it completes, but almost instantly. Its logged as a success, but the logic was not seemingly invoked.  I say seemingly because inside the lambda I am hooking into Redshift to run a data job that creates a table (if it doesn't exist), truncates that the table and inserts records; a full refresh of the data.

As noted above, the full refresh behaves as expected after the first invocation, but the following all complete quickly with no error.

I first noticed this when I was testing the connection between my Step Function and the lambda, and was attempting to chase setup/permission issues.

In short, if the expected lambda invocation runtime is about 60 seconds, why is seemingly caching the logic and not running the full job each time?  How can I force the full execution with each invocation, regardless if its myself testing on the console or the Step Function?

Comment: Please provide the relevant code which allows reproducing this behavior. Also if I'm reading your question correctly, this behavior happens without StepFunctions as well. If that's the case, please edit the question to remove the mention on StepFunctions.

Comment: This issue was due to the fact that I had all of my logic outside of the handler.  Once I moved the logic that the lambda was attempting to work through into the handler def, it worked as expected.  I was't really expecting caching to happen, but it appears to occur after the initial invocation.